# How to get rid of the decimal digits on the x axis

Tags: r

I want to create a simple plot.

```
year=c(2005,2006,2007)
dat=c(1,2,3)
plot(year,dat)
```

How can I only show the axis as the year without decimal digits?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `year` as a date, using `as.Date`.  Here is one way, using `seq.Date`:

```
year=seq(as.Date("2005/01/01"), by="1 year", length.out=3)
dat=c(1,2,3)
plot(year,dat)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

3 possible ways:

- Control the label resolution with `xaxp`:

  `plot(year,dat,xaxp=c(range(year),2))`
- Use a `Date` object for the x axis:

  `year2 <- as.Date(paste(year,"-01-01",sep=""))`

  `plot(year2,dat)`
- Construct the axis yourself:

  `plot(year,dat,xaxt="n")`

  `axis(1,at=year)`